# Why String being final makes application more safe?

Tags: java, string, security

For some time, I am trying to understand how String works, and I do not understand the aspect of security.

"In case, if String is not immutable, this would lead serious security threat, I mean someone can access to any file for which he has authorization, and then can change the file name either deliberately or accidentally and gain access to that file. Because of immutability, you don't need to worry about that kind of threats. This reason also gels with, Why String is final in Java, by making java.lang.String final, Java designer ensured that no one overrides any behavior of String class."

https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2010/10/why-string-is-immutable-or-final-in-java.html

String is immutable, so new object is created when we try to edit and a variable of type String has a new reference. If we can swap references, how is it safe? Someone could do just that and still get access to something he is not authorized to. Or maybe I do not understand this correctly?

Edit: Maybe I should rephrase my question. If String was mutable, how could security threat look like? Someone could access String pool and change the value there and in that way and for example unauthorized access to some file could be granted?

Comment: `In case, if String is not immutable, this would lead serious security threat, I mean someone can access to any file for which he has authorization, and then can change the file name either deliberately or accidentally and gain access to that file.` where did you find that claim?

Comment: Where did you copy pasted this from?

Comment: Generally speaking, you *can't* swap references, because java is purely pass-by-value.  Just because you can see that a process is pointing at `"/etc/passwword"` doesn't mean that you have any ability to modify that `String` so that it'll use `"/my/file"` instead.

Comment: https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2010/10/why-string-is-immutable-or-final-in-java.html

Comment: "Someone could do just that and still get access to something he is not authorized to." Could you make it gender neutral and put "they are not authorized" please?

Comment: Who is "Someone" Can you show an example of what you mean by someone else?

Comment: Someone besides the programmer who wants to access some file for example, or crash the app, or even maybe someone doing that by accident, maybe some other malicious program.

Comment: crashing an app is as easy as calling the function to terminate a process. also operating system bound. Java does not handle these types of things. If you're planning on distributing a java program to clients, regard that program as open source because java programs are decompilable. For "security" you may consider obfuscation.

Comment: I posted an edit, maybe that will help in understanding my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The [final](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/final.html) keyword provides a recommendation.

The String class is not labeled final to make the program more safe. It is labeled this way because it is a core language feature and so that programmers don't try to edit it. Editing it or extending functionality can change how this core feature works, and make the program behavior unpredictable, since the language depends on the String class being programmed the way it comes originally.

Any class can actually be modified if someone insists on doing so using [Reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/). However, it isn't possible to extend a final class.

In terms of security, there is no built-in security for your Java programs. Security such as handling what third party code can access your Java code or program memory is handled by the operating system.

Comment: I did not mean it like this.  I have for example a variable String s, and when I change it, changed value is printed. How is it safe then if i can do that?

Comment: There is no security or protection. If the operating system provides permission, a third party program can read the contents of your java program. Java doesnt encrypt its own memory or anything like that. But this is off topic now, we can continue in chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208199/chat-about-string-security

Comment: Unfortunately, I have less than 20 reputation here so I cannot talk in chat.